# GridView NullPointerException

Tags: android, gridview, nullpointerexception, fragment

Where am I going wrong?
Why this null pointer exception

```
    private class GridAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private LayoutInflater inflater;

    public GridAdapter(Context context) {
        Logger.d(TAG, "GridAdapter");
        inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        Logger.d("SIZE",""+AppConstants.getMenuList().size());
        return AppConstants.getMenuList().size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int i) {
        return AppConstants.getMenuList().get(i);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int i) {
        return i;
    }

    class ViewHolder {
        TextView title;
        RelativeLayout layout;
        ImageView image;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View view;
        if (convertView == null) {
            view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.inflater_grid_layout, null);
            ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
            viewHolder.layout = (RelativeLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.igl_layout);
            viewHolder.title = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.igl_name);
            viewHolder.image = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.igl_image);
            view.setTag(viewHolder);
        } else {
            view = convertView;
        }
        final ViewHolder holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
        MenuModel item = (MenuModel) getItem(position);
        holder.layout.setBackgroundColor(item.getColor());      //NULL POINTER HERE
        holder.title.setText(item.getName());
        holder.image.setImageResource(item.getImage());
        return view;
    }
}
```

This is my LogCat:

java.lang.NullPointerException
        at in.abm.indiape.fragments.GridMenuScreen$GridAdapter.getView(GridMenuScreen.java:115)
        at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2624)
        at android.widget.GridView.onMeasure(GridView.java:1045)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16831)
        at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChildHorizontal(RelativeLayout.java:728)
        at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:477)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16831)

Comment: if `convertView` is not `null` then `view.getTag();` returning null.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You `setTag` to view not to`convertView`. In the else part you have `view = convertView;`.

Then you have  `view.getTag()` which probably returns null when `convertView` is not null as suggested by prosper k.

There is no need to use `View view` you can directly use `convertView`.

So Change `getView` to

```
@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
     ViewHolder viewHolder;
    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView= inflater.inflate(R.layout.inflater_grid_layout, null);
        viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
        viewHolder.layout = (RelativeLayout) convertView.findViewById(R.id.igl_layout);
        viewHolder.title = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.igl_name);
        viewHolder.image = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.igl_image);
        convertView.setTag(viewHolder); // setTag if convertView is null
    } else {
        viewHolder = (ViewHolder)convertView.getTag();
        // get tag if convertView is not null
    }

    MenuModel item = (MenuModel) getItem(position);
    // update ui elements 
    viewHolder.layout.setBackgroundColor(item.getColor());      
    viewHolder.title.setText(item.getName());
    viewHolder.image.setImageResource(item.getImage());
    return convertView;
}
```

Comment: @user1991 post your `inflater_grid_layout.xml`

Comment: @user1991 does `inflater_grid_layout.xml` have  relative layout with id `igl_layout`. If not it gives you NPE. So post the xml.